# Azure Notification Hubs APIs - Benfits of DirectSend/DirectBatchSend vs. Registration/Notification/Tags styles

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

We're planning on implementing a server-side notification mechanism that pushes out to iOS and Android via ANH.  We will have no code footprint on our mobile clients, short of a call to our server API for "registration".  In this way our approach is looking similar to this [MSDN discussion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj927170.aspx#Anchor_1).

I also see the alternate, more [bare-bones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608572.aspx), approach noted on MSDN.

Is it fair to conclude that the two approaches will have similar performance on the 'send' side?

It appears the main difference is this:

- The former approach has already done the work of integrating with the Task and Async mechanism, presenting a callable C# mechanism that has taken on more of the RESTful API layer,
- The DirectBatch/Send API is just that -- the raw RESTful API for you to use as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For operations that are available as both REST API and SDK, you shouldn't see any significant difference in performance on the client side because the SDK is just a wrapper around the REST APIs. There are SDKs for both [iOS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started/) and [Android](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started/) and it's recommended to use those so that you don't have to re-write the wrapper.

Direct Send is only available in [.NET SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.senddirectnotificationasync.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendDirectNotificationAsync(Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Notification,System.Collections.Generic.IList%7BSystem.String%7D)) at the moment and for other platforms as REST API, so you'd have to implement your own wrapper in case you're using something other than .NET for the operation. You can [use the sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hubs-batch-direct-send/) to help you in the process.

In terms of performance it depends on what you mean by that.

- Direct send will most likely be delivered to customers a bit faster because ANH service doesn't have to do any registrations in the process, it just delivers notifications with your parameters. But it has it's limitations in terms of number of handles you can provide and also you need to manage handles yourself.
- If you only mean performance on the client side, then there should be no difference as all calls are asynchronous. And if you take advantage of tags, then you can do really tricky sends in one server call and let ANH figure out the details behind it.

But without knowing your scenario and requirements there's no way to give a proper recommendation.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaG..  Confirms what I thought.  One thing I notice in ANH generally, including the Direct Send APIs, is no HTTP 410 results -- what if the PNS device handle no longer exists (e.g. user uninstalled app from device)?  Does ANH detect that case or propagate a particular result back to the DirectSend caller?

Comment: @HowardHoffman, you can [retrieve PNS error details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/retrieve-platform-notification-system-error-details-with-azure-notification-hubs/). I've also updated the original answer with information about direct send availability as .NET SDK.